# Create Conditional Format for Row 1 and Want to Copy Down?

Tags: copy, google-sheets, highlight, gs-conditional-formatting

We have a spreadsheet of our locker combinations for our padlocks we issue to students (sample picture below)

[image]

In row 2, I set a CONDITIONAL FORMAT for CUSTOM FORMULA for cell C2 as =B2=1 to turn that cell Yellow. I can repeat for cells D2, E2, F2 and G2 so that if the head custodian puts in to use combo 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 that then the correct cell will highlight.

My problem is, how do I COPY that Conditional formatting down to the next rows so that the formula in the "custom formula" changes to work for B3 and B4 and B5 and so on?

I understand I can highlight and copy my first row and then PASTE SPECIAL > CONDITIONAL FORMATTING but the formula stays locked on for the first row of information rather than changing to the current row.  Maybe I need to use a different formula?

Comment: Solved! The Paste Special does in fact copy the formulas to the other rows and it works.  Not sure why...but it works.

Answer (score 0):

The Paste Special > CONDITIONAL FORMATTING does make the formula copied from one row work in other rows.  Was thrown off by the formula not changing and still showing the original row but it works.